# dependency inject Grails Webflow

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-webflow

Is it possible to inject a Spring bean into a Grails webflow? I tried the following

```
class CheckoutController {

    ShoppingService shoppingService

    def checkoutFlow = {
        start {
            action {
                // This attempt to access the service doesn't work
                flow.addresses = shoppingService.getOrder()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can access `shoppingService` from a regular controller action, but I can't access it from an action of the webflow (see above).

Comment: What errors do you get? My guess is, that WebFlow tries to store all accessed Domain objects in the flow-scope, giving some weird errors.

Comment: The service is null, so I get a NPE when I try to access the service. There are no domain objects involved in this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I thought what you listed was pseudocode but I made a sample app using your example and got the NPE as well.  I think it may be your flow structure that is the problem.  `action` blocks should go within a flow state.  Your flow definition should look something like:

```
class CheckoutController {
  ShoppingService shoppingService

  def checkoutFlow = {

     start {
       action {
         flow.addresses = shoppingService.getOrder()
         if(flow.addresses) {
            showForm()
         }
         else {
            showError()
         }
       }
       on("showForm").to "showForm"
       on("showError").to "showError"
     }

     showError {
        ...
     }
     //etc.
  }
}
```

You can definitely use injected services in your web flows.  I am guessing that the problem lies in your flow structure.

Answer (score 1):

add the following to your controller:

```
def transient shoppingService
```

Answer (score 1):

There are issues with dependency injection with webflows in controllers that contain traditional actions plus webflows.  It worked for me if the traditional action executed first.

see: 
[GRAILS-7095](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7095)
[GRAILS-4141](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-4141)

Webflows also break notions of **defaultAction** in mixed controllers.  I have found the first webflow wins and becomes the default action.

separately using **transient** keeps your service from be serialized between flow states. (e.g. don't  have to implement serializable)